# How can I make Rack::Session::Pool work in a test using Sinatra and RSpec?

Tags: rspec, sinatra

How can I make sessions work in my RSpec tests?

I have tried something like this:

```
describe "createnewlist_route_spec" do
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  use Rack::Session::Pool

  def app
    @app ||= Sinatra::Application
  end

  it "should save listitem to database" do
     post '/addnewlistitem', {:item => 'testitem'}, :sessions => {:userid => '123'} 
  end
end
```

I'm a noob to sinatra, so I might be on the wrong track here...

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem: http://gist.github.com/375973

Not quite what I wanted, but it works in my tests.