# How do I use omniauth in rspec for sinatra?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, sinatra, omniauth

**Shortened version:**

Using the omniauth gem for sinatra, I can't get rspec log in to work and keep my session for subsequent requests.

Based on suggestions from http://benprew.posterous.com/testing-sessions-with-sinatra, and turning off sessions, I've isolated the problem to this:

```rb
  app.send(:set, :sessions, false)    # From http://benprew.posterous.com/testing-sessions-with-sinatra
  get '/auth/google_oauth2/callback', nil, {"omniauth.auth" => OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google_oauth2] }
  # last_request.session => {"uid"=>"222222222222222222222", :flash=>{:success=>"Welcome"}}
  # last_response.body => ""

  follow_redirect!
  # last_request.session => {:flash=>{}}
  # last_response.body => Html for the homepage, which is what I want
```

How do I get rspec to follow the redirect and retain the session variables? Is this possible in Sinatra?

From http://benprew.posterous.com/testing-sessions-with-sinatra, it seems like I'd have to send the session variables on each get/post request that I require login for, but this wouldn't work in the case of redirects.

---

**The details:**

I'm trying to use the omniauth gem in sinatra with the following setup:

spec_helper.rb

```rb
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

# Include web.rb file
require_relative '../web'
# Include factories.rb file
require_relative '../test/factories.rb'

require 'rspec'
require 'rack/test'
require 'factory_girl'
require 'ruby-debug'

# Include Rack::Test in all rspec tests
RSpec.configure do |conf|
  conf.include Rack::Test::Methods
  conf.mock_with :rspec
end
```

web_spec.rb

```rb
describe "Authentication:" do
  before do
    OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
    OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:google_oauth2, {
      :uid => '222222222222222222222',
      :info => {
        :email => "someone@example.com",
        :name => 'Someone'
      }
    })
  end

  describe "Logging in as a new user" do
    it "should work" do
      get '/auth/google_oauth2/'

      last_response.body.should include("Welcome")
    end
  end
end
```

When trying to authenticate, I get a `<h1>Not Found</h1>` response. What am I missing?

On the [Integration testing](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing) page of the omniauth docs, it mentions adding two environment variables:

```rb
before do 
  request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user] 
  request.env["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:twitter] 
end
```

But seems to be for rails only, as I added

```rb
request.env["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google_oauth2]
```

to my `before` block in my spec and I get this error:

```rb
Failure/Error: request.env["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google_oauth2]
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

---

Edit:

Calling `get` with

```rb
get '/auth/google_oauth2/', nil, {"omniauth.auth" => OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google_oauth2]}
```

seems to give me `last_request.env["omniauth.auth"]` equal to

```rb
 {"provider"=>"google_oauth2", "uid"=>"222222222222222222222", "info"=>{"email"=>"someone@example.com", "name"=>"Someone"}}
```

which seems right, but `last_response.body` still returns

```rb
<h1>Not Found</h1>
```

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3892401/111884, which seems on track, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

A partial answer...

The callback url works better, with the added request environment variables:

```
get '/auth/google_oauth2/callback', nil, {"omniauth.auth" => OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google_oauth2]}
follow_redirect!

last_response.body.should include("Welcome")
```

However, this doesn't work with sessions after the redirect, which is required for my app to know someone is logged in. Updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Actually, I need sessions to work for login to work, so the answer doesn't really work for my app.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/375973) (originating from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3892401/111884) to store session data, I got my tests to store the session, allowing me to pass the session to further requests.

There might be an easier way though.

**Setup code:**

```rb
# Omniauth settings
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:google_oauth2, {
  :uid => '222222222222222222222',
  :info => {
    :email => "someone@example.com",
    :name => 'Someone'
  }
})


# Based on https://gist.github.com/375973 (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3892401/111884)
class SessionData
  def initialize(cookies)
    @cookies = cookies
    @data = cookies['rack.session']
    if @data
      @data = @data.unpack("m*").first
      @data = Marshal.load(@data)
    else
      @data = {}
    end
  end

  def [](key)
    @data[key]
  end

  def []=(key, value)
    @data[key] = value
    session_data = Marshal.dump(@data)
    session_data = [session_data].pack("m*")
    @cookies.merge("rack.session=#{Rack::Utils.escape(session_data)}", URI.parse("//example.org//"))
    raise "session variable not set" unless @cookies['rack.session'] == session_data
  end
end

def login!(session)
  get '/auth/google_oauth2/callback', nil, { "omniauth.auth" => OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google_oauth2] }
  session['uid'] = last_request.session['uid']

  # Logged in user should have the same uid as login credentials
  session['uid'].should == OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google_oauth2]['uid']
end

# Based on Rack::Test::Session::follow_redirect!
def follow_redirect_with_session_login!(session)
  unless last_response.redirect?
    raise Error.new("Last response was not a redirect. Cannot follow_redirect!")
  end

  get(last_response["Location"], {}, { "HTTP_REFERER" => last_request.url, "rack.session" => {"uid" => session['uid']} })
end

def get_with_session_login(path)
  get path, nil, {"rack.session" => {"uid" => session['uid']}}
end
```

**Sample rspec code:**

```rb
describe "Authentication:" do

  def session
    SessionData.new(rack_test_session.instance_variable_get(:@rack_mock_session).cookie_jar)
  end

  describe "Logging in as a new user" do
    it "should create a new account with the user's name" do
      login!(session)
      last_request.session[:flash][:success].should include("Welcome")

      get_with_session_login "/"
      follow_redirect_with_session_login!(session)
      last_response.body.should include("Someone")
    end
  end
end
```